# Databse migration based on SQL in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Does Laravel allow to use database migration based on ready SQL created in Workbench as an option?

As I know, now it suggests to write migration file manually following the specific format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there's nothing preventing you from running SQL in a migration. You can use `DB::statement()` to do this inside of `up()` in your migration.

```
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::statement('
        create table application_pages_test
        (
            id int unsigned auto_increment
                primary key,
            application_id tinyint unsigned not null,
            title varchar(64) not null,
            created_at timestamp null,
            updated_at timestamp null
        )
        collate=utf8_unicode_ci
    ;');
```

Comment: Okay, and where to put SQL quest in this code  segment?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "SQL quest".

Comment: SQL query, sorry it is typo

Comment: Any SQL query can go in the string. I just have a `create table` statement as an example. If you have multiple SQL statements (multiple semicolons), you'll need to split the lines and call them with `DB::statement()` individually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Laravel allows the use of ready SQL created in Workbench. You just have to connect your Laravel application to the database, and you should be fine.

The use of migrations in Laravel is not mandatory, but very useful in tracking versions your database structure.

Since tracking the structure of your database is very essential, I recommend you try one of these packages to convert your SQL to Laravel migrations:

1. [MySQL Workbench Export Laravel 5 Migrations Plugin](https://github.com/beckenrode/mysql-workbench-export-laravel-5-migrations) – plugin for
   a popular software [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), written in Python language
2. [Laravel Migration Exporter for Sequel Pro](https://github.com/cviebrock/sequel-pro-laravel-export) – A bundle for Sequel
   Pro that lets you generate Laravel migration files from existing
   tables. Written in PHP language.
3. [Xethron Laravel Migrations Generator](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator) – Laravel artisan-command
   tool, available as Laravel package

[Source](https://laraveldaily.com/review-3-tools-generate-laravel-migrations-existing-database/)

Comment: Without creating migration files? Or do you mean just export SQL from workbench and import to exist database? But what about models Laravel then?

Comment: You can go either ways. I have updated the answer with packages to help you convert SQL to Laravel migrations.

Answer (score 0):

A few weeks ago we released support for Laravel framework for our visual editor Skipper (https://www.skipper18.com). From your question I suppose, it might be very useful for you.

You can import your project from a database (MySql, Postgres, MSSQL or Sqlite) and you will get a clear graphical diagram of it which you can then automatically export to model classes and migrations files.

In addition, you can make changes in the model and create new migrations and repetitively export all changes back to Laravel PHP files. All of this via a user-friendly interface.

If you want to try it, it's completely free during the beta period. You can download it here https://www.skipper18.com/en/download and in the initial application license screen select "Laravel Beta license".